# How long does the Cloud9's Apache httpd server last

Tags: apache, web, web-hosting, cloud9-ide

I have a website which I would like to host just to show it to other people. For now I do not wish to bother myself with web hosting services, domain registrations and so on. And so happens Cloud9's simple hosting does the trick. Hosting stops working after a certain amount of time. I want to know after how long does it exactly stop working and hosting? I plan to restart the apache to host it again and again, everyday if needed, I just want to know after approximately how many hours should I schedule this restart.

Appreciate any answers, even the ones who tell how to free host using any other services. Mind that URL and domain name are irrelevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud9's Apache server will not stop until you ask it to.

Your workspace will hibernate after a period of inactivity (for free users, it is 2 days), which will shut down all processes running on your workspace. It will remain in that state till you next need to access it, at which point it will start up, but it won't restart your server automatically yet. You'll have to do that manually for now.

In the above statement, inactivity means not having logged into that workspace. So, as long as you're visiting the workspace daily, the workspace will not hibernate.

Why? Because Cloud9 is a development environment, and not a hosting platform. Not accessing your workspace, and coding on it means that you probably don't need the running application after a while.